# NHibernate many-to-one by formula?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2, and would like to load a many-to-one association using a formula.

Given an arbitrary domain entity E[X], there is a calculation to derive the primary key of the previous entity E[X-1]. I'd like each entity to be loaded as a node in a linked list, with each entity having a "Previous" property which is loaded lazily using this formula, so I can traverse the history if I like.

In other words, no direct reference to the previous entry is stored in the current entry, but a formula is available to compute the previous key.

I've tried to specify "formula" for a many-to-one, but of course it fails with "property mapping has wrong number of columns". Any other suggestions for achieving this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug in the NHibernate 2.x series. I upgraded to the NHibernate 3.0 beta, and the problems were resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This would best be accomplished using a PostLoadEventListener.

Comment: This looks doable, but before I put too much work into it, how can I ensure that the "previous" entity is lazily loaded? I've specified all the necessary information in the mapping file, but I don't see interfaces available via the PostLoadEvent which allow me to specify a proxy be returned instead of the concrete class.

Comment: I think I found it in the IEntityPersister interface accessible via the PostLoadEvent class. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Did some preliminary testing and I'm afraid these event listeners are brutally slow; I'm talking 3-4x slowdown over previous behaviour, and that's without even creating the proxy (just some type tests on loaded objects). I don't see an easy way to reduce the data set to make this overhead manageable, so this solution won't work for me.

Comment: I'm surprised by the 3-4x slowdown. NHibernate is internally implemented in terms of listeners. So I suspect that it's something that you're doing in your listener code. Can you post it?

Comment: The OnPostLoad method is trivial: I do a simple type test. The problem is that the number of results being processed is high, so this callback is invoked thousands of times where before there was no overhead. I'm not surprised it's so expensive. This is not the ideal path to place this. However, it seems like I was using an outdated schema and the new one I downloaded supports formula in many-to-one. I'm still getting errors though, and there's no guidance on this usage in the manual. Frustrating to say the least.

Comment: Sounds like we can investigate two different options... Can you post your OnPostLoad method and some stats on approximately how many times it is called? And the error message(s) when using the many-to-one formula would also help in resolving this... I agreee that the lesser known areas of NHibernate can be frustrating, but that is true of all software. Fortunately we have source that we can debug through to reveal the mysteries. :)